# Java math operations on variable number of arguments

Tags: java

I'm new at starting object oriented programming. I have tried to find a topic that would answer my questions, but I haven't seem to find my answers yet. I hope I'll get help ^^

I am trying to understand something. I have the following class:

```
      class Employee {

            private String SIN ; // format "123 456 789", ex : "250 343 567"
            private double salWeek ; // example 1075.25 $
            . . . Constructors to write . . .
            . . . Other methods to write . . .} // End of Employee class
```

I have to create the following constructors:

```
      Employee emp1 = new Employee("321 498 726", 987.50); // 987.50$ is Total salary for week
      Employee emp2 = new Employee("135 444 321", 45.00, 20.00); /* 45 hr x 20$/hr. 
                                                                 900.00 $ is Total salary for week*\
```

And I have to print informations on the second employee with the following method:

```
      emp2.print("Informations of second employee");
```

to get

```
      SIN: 135 444 321
      Weekly Salary: 900.00$ per week
```

I am a bit confused since I have two entering arguments for the salary (45 and 20) on which I was thinking doing a math operation (45*20). I just don't seem to understand how to do it.

I then have to modify and print emp1 salary using emp2 salary and adding 123.25$ (giving a total of 1023.25$).

Is it possible to let me know how I could do it? I have code parts if needed.

Thank you!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class Employee {

  private String SIN ;
  private double salWeek;

  public String getNAS() {

    return NAS;
    }

  public double getsalWeek() { //Needs work since emp2 has 2 arguments

    /*I was thinking here of adding math operation to get second and third argument and make multiplication if salary has 2 arguments*/

    return salWeek;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Employee emp1 = new Employee("321 498 726", 987.50);
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("135 444 321", 45.00, 20.00); //Weekly salary is 45 * 20

    emp2.display("Informations on second employee");
        System.out.printf("NAS: %s\n",emp2.getNAS());
        System.out.printf("Weekly salary:        %d\n",emp2.getsalWeek());
        }
    }
```

Edit: Clarification on variables + code part. Code part is NOT complete and needs work.

Comment: Please add the code you have to the question. Also your question is quite vauge. Be more specific and relate your question to your code.

Comment: Seems, your first problem is not finding the answer but understanding the question.

Comment: @Henry You can share anything about the question you seem to understand more than I do. This is my first post and I'm here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
printInfo(Employee e){
  System.out.println("SIN : " + e.getSIN());
  System.out.println("Weekly Salary : " + e.getSalHabdo()*e.getSecondSal());
}
```

Please note that the above method assumes that you have three fields in your class - SIN, salHebdo and the third one which you're setting in the second constructor.

edit-1 : Please provide the getter and setter code of your class and clarification on the third field you're setting using the constructor.